# Creating a batch fies to Move compress and delete

Tags: batch-file, winzip

Just wondering if anyone knows how to create a batch to file move files from one location to another, compresses the files(withwinzip) being moved and then delete the orginal files every month??

Many Thanks

Michael Osei

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use WinZip to compress the files, first install the [WinZip Command Line Support Add-On](http://www.winzip.com/prodpagecl.htm). The add-on comes with documentation that shows exactly how to use the tool from a batch script.

To delete files from a batch script, use the [del command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/del.mspx). To delete directories from a batch script, use the [rmdir command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rmdir.mspx).

To run the script once a month, create a [Scheduled Task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Schedule-a-task).